# UITableView(Cell) doesn't listen to clipToBounds = NO when animating to outside of cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have this CustomTableViewCell that involves a couple of info-labels and an image.
This image is an arrow that hides behind the cell when not selected but shows when the cell gets selected.

Unselected cell:
| "i" >|

Selected cell:
| "i"  |>

Previously I worked with xCode 4.5 and compiled with SDK 6.1 and all was fine. When I selected the cell the arrow animated to the right and was perfectly visible.
However I recently started using xCode 5.0.2 and SDK 7.0 and this functionality stopped working. The image is still getting moved but it stopped being visible.

All involved UIViews of the cell as well as the UITableView are set to .clipsToBounds = NO;

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening after the upgrade to the new SDK and xCode?
Can I solve this behaviour easily to the functionality it had in the previous version?

Comment: Are you using autolayout? Are you sure that the view hierarchy is still correct and that the image is actually getting moved? Can you post a screenshot of the hierarchy taken with the Reveal app?

Comment: The image is actually getting moved. For testing purposes I made the arrow visible by bringing it to the front with bringSubviewToFront:. The animation is being done but is clipped when getting pushed over the edge of the cell. With the 6.1 SDK this is not the case, then it will stay visible. But with 7.0 SDK the arrow gets clipped. If I change the animation so that is is half over the edge and have on the cell it only shows half of the arrow (the part that is still on the cell)